# how to change text to numeric in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, types, compiler-errors

I want to convert a cell content to numeric values so that I can compare values.

```
If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(157, c) Then Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 3)
```

I need help on how to do it

```
Sub comp_above_median()

For c = 6 To 19
 i = 160

    For r = 2 To 155
        If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(157, c) Then Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 3)
        If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(157, c) Then i = i + 1

    Next r

Next c

End Sub
```

i am getting Runtime error 13 : type mismatch for the line

```
If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(157, c) Then Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 3)
```

Comment: Is the number a string? If so, you can use CInt().

Comment: @lowpar i am not sure, how to check ?

Comment: @lowpar after adding the cint() the condition is not giving the right results it always giving true

Comment: next time, put value into a msgbox to see what it is, after try and do sum simple math to see if its a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
    Sub comp_above_median()
    For c = 6 To 19
     i = 160
        For r = 2 To 155
            If Val(Cells(r, c)) >= Val(Cells(157, c)) Then
            Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 3)
            i = i + 1
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
    End Sub
```

Comment: i tried this same thing but the condition line is always returning true    If CInt(Cells(r, c)) >= CInt(Cells(157, c)) Then

Comment: Could you try `Val` instead of `CInt`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to end the if statements and write the if procedure in another line:

```
    If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(157, c) Then 
        Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 3)
        i = i + 1
    End if
```

Comment: Yeah my bad i missed it